# IE back button behaves differently than Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer, filtering, back-button

I have a web application using ASP.net with a MS SQL Server back end. Here is the basic problem. Page1 has a series of DDLs that function as filters and a "Go" button to apply those filters reloading Page1's repeater. The Go button click also saves those filter settings to a users table in SQL. When the user comes back to Page1 even after logging out and closing browsers those filters are applied next time he/she visits the site. Page2 takes the user to the details of a record from Page1. A menu at the top in the master page allows the user to get from any page back to Page1.

In Chrome all works as expected no matter if the user uses the navigation link up top or the back button, or closes browser and comes back at a later date.

In IE the back button does not work, but the navigation link or new browser does. In IE the previous filters are present not the new ones just selected prior to clicking/saving via "Go" button.

Client's standard Build is IE 10 and that is not flexible. Chrome is not an option.

How can I get the back button in IE to behave like Chrome?

Thanks!

To be clear this is the order of operation.

1. User goes to Page1 and sees list of 20 items with old filter values set
2. User changes DDLs and click Go button (filters saved to DB)
3. User sees new list of 10 items on Page1 and click one of those 10 items
4. User goes to Page2 details of that clicked item on
5. User clicks back button. In IE they see 20 items (original filter) in Chrome they see 10 items correct, most recently set filter.

Comment: You said - "When the user comes back to Page1 even after logging out and closing browsers those filters are applied next time he/she visits the site".  How are you looking them up on a return visit?  A cookie I assume?  If so are you sure this is a back button issue and not a cookie issue?  If you're sure about it being a back button issue, check out this page and see if helps.  http://madhatted.com/2013/6/16/you-do-not-understand-browser-history

Comment: On page Load if it is not a post back we get those settings form the database and set all the DDLs prior to loading the repeater.